# Is it possible to access Apple mail over IMAP using Apple Sign In?

Tags: imap, apple-sign-in

Apple enables sign in with Apple REST API that seems quite similar to one of OAuth2 authorization/authentication flows. It would be really helpful to have this method of authentication for IMAP protocol. Unfortunately I have not found any proof of it:

1. Apple IMAP configuration recommendations state that users should use auto-generated passwords for IMAP
2. IMAP CAPABILITY request has no trace of OAUTH.

Can anyone confirm that "Apple Sign In" is applicable or not applicable to IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

Apple says you need to use a special app-password when using IMAP. A user can generate that password in their iCloud account.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397

Comment: Thanks but this does not help. The question was about an option to access IMAP service through Apple Sign In procedure that is quite similar to OAuth2 protocol.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Only GIMAP (Gmail) supported XOAuth2 IMAP extension in the past, to the best of my knowledge: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol